# Change KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS env var in master GKE

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster on GKE with many pods and persistent disks (PD) and cannot deploy anymore.

```
pod failed to fit in any node fit failure on node (XX): MaxVolumeCount
```

The issue should not affect me because I have a 2-code machine and Google recently raised the persistent disk limit to 64:

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/04/enhanced-persistent-disks-for-Google-Compute-Engine-better-Kubernetes-and-Docker-support.html

The problems seems to be a env var in the master that says `KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS = 16`. The issue seems to be fixed but since I have a hosted master I cannot find the way to change the env var.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24317#issuecomment-214556057

So the question is:

*How can I change an env var in a GKE master?*

Comment: An answer to a similar question has been posted on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004628/maxgcepdvolumecount-in-google-container-engine?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: I saw the discussion was carry out also [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24317) and there has been some progress but not an ideal solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Google Container Engine is a managed environment so it won't allow you to set env vars on the master.

Options to move this forward will be:

- Run your own Kubernetes cluster on GCE instead of GKE.
- Submit a
  [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) to GKE to provide this feature under 'Container
  Engine' component.
- The [Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24317#issuecomment-214556057) that you posted is still open, so
  you might wait for a complete solution.